# Which AWS services to pick for the right architecture?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, elastic-load-balancer

AWS seems a little daunting with too many overlapping services so I'm looking for some advice and direction.

We have a mobile app for which we've developed a sync server (i.e. user will sign-up, sync data kept on AWS). Currently we've setup an EC2 instance with a web server, Django end-points and a postgres server. However we need the following:

1. Ensure the service is available from different regions of the
   world for faster access
2. If that requires putting the postgres server outside of the EC2, what service do we need and how would replication work?
3. We will have larger file attachments stored on S3 separately, but need to do this securely and encrypt the files
4. Eventually we will host a web-app (i.e. an Angular 2 app) that would
   connect to the same database.

We also would need to do all this in the most economical way and then scale up as the load increases.

Please any guidance would be appreciated. I'm struggling with terminologies at the moment. We also setup an Amazon SSL Certificate however that requires an Elastic Load Balancer but we only have one EC2 instance. What do we do to get this all working securely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information provided, I would recommend you to start with AWS Elastic Beanstalk, where it will manage autoscaling and loadbalancing while providing you with a DNS URL for external domain mapping.

1. To ensure that the service is available from different regions for faster access, you can cache the static Angular App using Cloudfront. Then you will be able to add SSL Certificate to Cloudfront instead of ELB. If you plan to create multiple environments for different regions, you can use Route53 for geo based routing.
2. To take Postgres server outside EC2, you can use AWS RDS and it supports synchronous replication with fail-over for Multi-AZ deployments and also Postgres in RDS also supports [Cross Region Replication](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/06/amazon-rds-for-postgresql-now-supports-cross-region-read-replicas/) if you plan to setup multiple deployment environments in different regions. Also you can create Read Replicas to improve reading speeds which will be asynchronously replicated.
3. You can encrypt the files in S3 using AES256 using Keys from KMS or from your client and I would recommend using [Signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) with Cloudfront in front of S3 serving these files, so that clients can securely and directly access them improving the performance by getting advantage from distributed caching.
4. You can host the Angular App in AWS S3 and Cache using Cloudfront for faster access. Another option is to cache the static asset path in Cloudfront so that subsequent requests for static assets will be served from Cloudfront.

[FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/faqs/) from Amazon

> **Who should use AWS Elastic Beanstalk?**
>   Those who want to deploy and manage their applications within minutes
>   in the AWS Cloud. You don’t need experience with cloud computing to
>   get started. AWS Elastic Beanstalk supports Java, .NET, PHP, Node.js,
>   **Python**, Ruby, Go, and Docker web applications.

Comment: A correction on 2 - fail-over replication is STRICTLY Synchronous. You can use asynchronous failover with read replicas only, but a Multi-AZ instance is inherently synchronous (otherwise it'd be kind of useless).

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the suggestion. Verified with the docs and I will update the correction accordingly. At the time I was checking Oracle in RDS didn't have synchronous replication, which I assumed to the same for Postgres

Comment: ah, no. A mutli-AZ failover replica is always synchronous, but can NOT be used for reading etc, for example. Asynchronous as stated is read replicas :)

Answer (score 0):

Your current environment isn't scalable (either load-responsive or to another region). If you need scalability then it should be re-arranged. It is difficult to provide you with details because the required environment depends on the applications architecture, however there are some suggestions:

- DB: For better stability multi-AZ RDS setup for the DB is recommended. Benefit is RDS is fully managed service so you don't need to worry about replication, maintenance etc.
- Web/app servers: you can deploy a copy in any region you want and connect to the same DB.
- S3: you can enable crosss-region replication as well as encryption, but make sure it is used wisely (e.g. files are served to the client from bucket in closest region)
- You can set up your own SSL on the server and it does not require ELB. However, you can use ELB with one webnode only.
- I do NOT suggest to use Beanstalk because despite it really makes the first steps more easier you may have trouble trying to configure something non-standard in the future (unless you're very well familiar with EBT, of course).
- To add efficiency you may want to add CDN (either AWS ot another vendor).

Make sure your environment configuration is really secure. You may need for your team someone who is familiar with AWS because every topic can be converted to a separate article.

Comment: Correction for DB: Postgres in RDS support cross region replication
Source: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/06/amazon-rds-for-postgresql-now-supports-cross-region-read-replicas/

Comment: For Web/app servers: Its not recommended to keep web servers in one region and use DB server from another region, which will heavily impact performance due to cross regional latency. 
Refer: https://serverfault.com/questions/511325/aws-multi-region-setup-using-single-rds-instance

Its recommended to do SSL offloading either at Cloudfront or ELB
Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43440757/ssl-offloading-on-aws-cloudfront-level/43441805?noredirect=1#comment73944768_43441805

Comment: @Ahsan thanks for the replies and comments, this surely helps. However the link you shared seems to be something similar to what we're trying to achieve and I guess even with RDS we'll run into the issue of performance, i.e. we have a DB where writes / reads are frequent and would need faster access from both US and EU. I'm still uncertain as to what we need to do :/

Comment: Faster - how much, in milliseconds? 
If you need really quick writes you should not send the write queries overseas. Speed of light limit cannot be canceled but you can build architecture which uses local resources.

Comment: @Ashan thanks for the correction. RE: offload to ELB: I suggested to set up the cert on the instance assuming he does not want ELB.

Comment: @strangetimes  If even local speed is not good for you - check DynamoDB.